# Can't connect to EC2 Ethereum node from AWS Lambda

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, nodes, aws

I tried to continue the discussion on this similar question: [Connection Error - Couldn't connect to ethereum node on AWS at http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8545](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/connection-error-couldnt-connect-to-ethereum-node-on-aws-at-http-xx-xxx-xx). Mods told me to create a new one so here goes.

I have an EC2 instance running an Ethereum node (Parity in my case). The instance is public to the world. I can run some simple code on my local machine at home and connect to the AWS instance:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
let web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://<EC2_PUBLIC_IP>:8545')
)
console.log(web3.eth.blockNumber)
```

This works fine from any computer that can connect to the internet.

I want to set up a Lambda function that can set up a web3 connection to this node. I've tried a simple function like this:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  let web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      'http://<EC2_PUBLIC_IP>:8545'
    )
  )
  callback(
    null,
    success({
      blockNumber: web3.eth.blockNumber
    })
  )
}
```

When I run this, I always get the error:

```
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://<EC2_PUBLIC_IP>:8545.
```

I have tried everything and verified that the Lambda can talk to the EC2 by serving an HTTP request (they are in the same VPC). I tried to use the private IP instead of public, DNS instead of IP address, everything.

I've read that people have been able to have Lambda functions call contracts, so I think this has to be possible.

Any ideas on what we can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest Web3 (1.0.0 beta) and somehow the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that web3 changed between 0.20 and 1.0.0-beta31 from synchronous to asynchronous.

This is how I got it running with web3@1.0.0-beta.31

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let ip = '123.123.123.123';
  let web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      'http://' + ip + ':8545'
    )
  )

  function s1(res) {
    console.log("SUCC: " + res);
    callback(null, res);
  }

  function f1(err) {
    console.log("ERR: " + err);
    callback(err, null);
  }

  web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(s1, f1);
}
```